# How C++ lambda move capture *this in rvalue reference member function?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, combinators

we can move capture variable in c++ as follow.

```
string s;
auto f = [s = std::move(s)](){ /* do something */ };
```

we can copy capture ***this*** as follow.

```
auto f = [*this](){ /* do something */ };
```

but how can we move capture ***this*** in rvalue reference member function?

```
class Obj {
  // ...
  auto method() && {
      // do something.
      return [ /* "*this = std::move(*this)" is a syntax error */ ](){
        // do something.
      };
  }
  // ...
};
```

Comment: `[obj = std::move(*this)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can normally assign it to a variable. ;-)

```
class Obj {
  // ...
  auto method() && {
      // do something.
      return [self = std::move(*this)](){
        // Use self.member here
      };
  }
  // ...
};
```

Note that the type of `self` is `const Obj`. If you want it to be non `const`, you have to make the lambda `mutable`.

```
[self = std::move(*this)]()mutable{
    // Use self.member here
}
```